# Ubuntu Server with X11 minimal instalation for KODI

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, kodi

im trying to install minimal Ubuntu Server 15.04 with X11 and functional KODI.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install kodi xinit xorg xserver-xorg-video-ati`

At this point, im able to run kodi with xinit /usr/bin/kodi

But when i try to run kodi with /usr/bin/kodi, here is the output:

`user@htpc:~$ kodi
 Error: unable to open display
 Kodi needs hardware accelerated OpenGL rendering.
 Install an appropriate graphics driver.
 Please consult Kodi Wiki for supported hardware
 http://kodi.wiki/view/Supported_hardware`

Glxinfo show same error

`user@htpc:~$ glxinfo
 Error: unable to open display`

Can anyone explain it to me, please? Even this isnt working
Do I need install some other packages?

`user@htpc:~$ DISPLAY=:0.0 kodi
 Error: unable to open display :0.0
 Kodi needs hardware accelerated OpenGL rendering.
 Install an appropriate graphics driver.
 Please consult Kodi Wiki for supported hardware
 http://kodi.wiki/view/Supported_hardware`

Thanks

Comment: Why not just install something like Kodibuntu and be done with it?